# localStorage Update Cannot Find innerHTML Value - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, innerhtml

I have been refactoring some of my `innerHTML` content within a form to make it more readable. Before, I had one lump `innerHTML` which was hard to read, however worked and allowed updating to `localStorage`.

I gave each div wrapper its own unique ID so that I could change the `innerHTML` value, in order to make everything neater and readable, this worked fine but when I try to edit my form now it gives me an error of `cannot set property 'fname' of undefined`. When I revert it back to the lump html it edits fine?

My knowledge is limited of how JS works, so can anyone explain why this might be happening, and is there a resolution?

Here's my code and edit handler (simplified), it's difficult to show on this as it's using localStorage but hopefully it's at least helpful:

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e) {
  var disabled = true;

  $(".required").each(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    if (!(value) || (value.trim() === '') || ($(this).hasClass('is-invalid'))) {
      disabled = false;
      $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  if (disabled) {
    $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", false);
  }

});

var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];

$("#submit").click(function() {

  var newBookings = {
    id: new Date().getTime(),
    fname: $('#fname').val(),
    lname: $('#lname').val(),
  }

  bookings.push(newBookings);
  var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
  window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

  showBooking();
  document.getElementById('formSuccess').style.display = "block";

});

$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var parent_form = $('this.form');

  var fname = parent_form.find('.fname').val();
  var lname = parent_form.find('.lname').val();

  let i = bookings.findIndex(booking => booking.id == $(this).data("id"));

  bookings[i].fname = fname;
  bookings[i].lname = lname;

  var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
  window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

  alert('Form updated!');
  window.location.reload();
  showBooking();

});

function showBooking() {
  var bookingResult = document.getElementById("result");
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  bookingResult.innerHTML = `<h3 class="text-center">Your Bookings</h3>`;
  for (let i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
    bookingResult.innerHTML += `
<div class="card card-body bg-light  m-4"> 
<div class="row">
<p>Owner name: ${bookings[i].fname + " " + bookings[i].lname}</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
<button onclick="editBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-outline-danger ">Edit</button>
<button onclick="deleteBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-danger text-light ">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>                          
</div>`;
  }
}

function editBooking(i) {
  $('#result').hide();
  var fnameEdit = document.getElementById("fnameEdit");
  var lnameEdit = document.getElementById("lnameEdit");

  var editButton = document.getElementById("editBtn");

  fnameEdit.innerHTML = `<input type="text" class="fname form-control required" data-id="${bookings[i].id}" placeholder="First Name" name="${bookings[i].fname}" value="${bookings[i].fname}" required>`;

  lnameEdit.innerHTML = `
<input type="text" class="lname form-control required" data-id="${bookings[i].id}" placeholder="Last Name" name="${bookings[i].lname}" value="${bookings[i].lname}" required>`;

  editButton.innerHTML = `<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
<input id="edit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Edit">
<a href="index.html" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Cancel</a>
</div>`;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="" class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="fnameEdit" class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="input form-control required" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
    </div>
    <div id="lnameEdit" class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="input form-control required" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="editBtn">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="submit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="result" class="row"></div>
  <div id="currentItem" class="row"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Hi, this `$('this.form')` should be `$(this).closest('form')` then try again . Also , i am not able to run this is this your real code ?

Comment: Yes, I have just shortened it a bit, it won't run correctly on here or codepen, not sure why.

Comment: Still giving me the same error, I'll try and get it working on codepen. Hold on.

Comment: https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/yLaEYoV

Comment: It is coming up with `not found`, I think maybe because of reloads?

Comment: You have `type="submit"` in your button ?

Comment: Yes. It works when I put it into one large innerHTML, but once I broke it down and wrapped with individual `id's` it threw errors.

Comment: Your `bookings.findIndex..` is returning `-1` did you tried below answer suggestion ?

Comment: The below suggestion would only solve the issue for that one field, I have multiple fields and they will all have the same error.

Comment: I have updated my codepen with a new trial, still giving me the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is described in the comment by @Swati  (i.e.: $(this).closest('form'))

As a consequence, the second issue is related to the anonymous function you use inside [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

Change this part from:

```
let i = bookings.findIndex(booking => booking.id == $(this).data("id"));
```

to:

```
let i = bookings.findIndex(booking => booking.id == parent_form.find('.fname').data("id"));
```

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.required', function(e) {
  var disabled = true;

  $(".required").each(function() {
      var value = this.value;
      if (!(value) || (value.trim() === '') || ($(this).hasClass('is-invalid'))) {
          disabled = false;
          $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", true);
      }
  });

  if (disabled) {
      $('.toggle-disabled').prop("disabled", false);
  }

});

var bookings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookings")) || [];

$("#submit").click(function() {

  var newBookings = {
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      fname: $('#fname').val(),
      lname: $('#lname').val(),
  }

  bookings.push(newBookings);
  var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
  window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

  showBooking();
  document.getElementById('formSuccess').style.display = "block";

});

$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var parent_form = $(this).closest('form');

  var fname = parent_form.find('.fname').val();
  var lname = parent_form.find('.lname').val();


  let i = bookings.findIndex(booking => booking.id == parent_form.find('.fname').data("id"));

  bookings[i].fname = fname;
  bookings[i].lname = lname;

  var json = JSON.stringify(bookings);
  window.localStorage.setItem("bookings", json);

  alert('Form updated!');
  window.location.reload();
  showBooking();

});

function showBooking() {
  var bookingResult = document.getElementById("result");
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  bookingResult.innerHTML = `<h3 class="text-center">Your Bookings</h3>`;
  for (let i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
      bookingResult.innerHTML += `
  <div class="card card-body bg-light  m-4">
              <div class="row">
              <p>Owner name: ${bookings[i].fname + " " + bookings[i].lname}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
              <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
              <button onclick="editBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-outline-danger ">Edit</button>
              <button onclick="deleteBooking(${i})" class="col-md-4 btn btn-danger text-light ">Delete</button>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>`;
  }
}

function editBooking(i) {
  $('#result').hide();
  var fnameEdit = document.getElementById("fnameEdit");
  var lnameEdit = document.getElementById("lnameEdit");

  var editButton = document.getElementById("editBtn");

  fnameEdit.innerHTML = `<input type="text" class="fname form-control required" data-id="${bookings[i].id}" placeholder="First Name" name="${bookings[i].fname}" value="${bookings[i].fname}" required>`;

  lnameEdit.innerHTML = `
<input type="text" class="lname form-control required" data-id="${bookings[i].id}" placeholder="Last Name" name="${bookings[i].lname}" value="${bookings[i].lname}" required>`;

  editButton.innerHTML = `<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
          <input id="edit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Edit">
          <a href="index.html" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Cancel</a>
          </div>`;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="fnameEdit" class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="input form-control required" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
        </div>
        <div id="lnameEdit" class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="input form-control required" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="editBtn">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="submit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="result" class="row"></div>
    <div id="currentItem" class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats fine, but I have multiple inputs and the errors will be the same for all of them, this was just the initial error, so the error will be the same for all fields.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem eventually, I hadn't given the attributes a new ID and somehow, that sorted the issue. I removed the innerHTML and replaced with setAttribute methods which work fine.

Thanks for help!

Something along these lines:

```
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
    var editButton = document.getElementById("editBtn");

    fname.setAttribute('data-id', bookings[i].id);
    fname.setAttribute('value', bookings[i].fname);
    lname.setAttribute('data-id', bookings[i].id);
    lname.setAttribute('value', bookings[i].lname);

    editButton.innerHTML = `<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
<input data-id="${bookings[i].id}" id="edit" class="btn btn-danger toggle-disabled" type="submit" value="Edit" disabled>
<a href="index.html" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Cancel</a>
</div>`;
```